# Customize Lightning History Utility

Tags: lightning, console, app

Is there any way, how we could adjust an offered records of the **History Utility** in Lightning Console App?

Let's assume a use case, where I want to **exclude** Case Tabs from the recent tabs history (preferably only for a profile *XY_User*)?[image: example]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. It's an out of the box utility with no customization options - not even allowing you to change anything like the label or icon for it. As is, it'll do as [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.console_lex_custom_utilities_history.htm&type=5) which'll include any tab visited:

> - The list can display up to 10 workspace tabs at a time, with 10
>   subtabs under each workspace tab.
> - Workspace tabs are listed in the
>   order last visited, with the most recent at the top. Subtabs are
>   listed under their primary tabs in the order first opened.

Your *best bet* would be to create an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy) asking for customization options on that provided utility.

Otherwise, you'd have to look at creating your own utility component to do this - you can have a [LWC utility component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_config_for_utility_bar) and can see what tab a user is on through [focused tab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getFocusedTabInfo.htm). You'd have to store each tab they visit so you could display a filtered history per profile. I wouldn't recommend going custom as it's typically not a good idea to re-create standard components (your responsibility with maintenance, issues) unless it's truly missing something critical.

Comment: Thank you you for the confirmation Kris! Kind regards